# How to format a four-digit number + special decimals in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a dataset in Excel with numbers like this:

```
3254539306640620
325.403.955.078.125
3.254.041015625
```

etc..

What I need is to format the numbers to four digits + 2 decimals rounded to .00, .25, .50, .75

In the end the format should look like this, according to the numbers in the example:

```
3254.50
3254.25
3254.00
```

Any Ideas how to accomplish this in Excel?
Thank you!

Comment: You second number would round to `.00` not `.25` as `3254.03` is closer to `.00` than `.25`

Comment: Yes you're right. It was meant for a demonstrative purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remove all the `.` with SUBSTITUTE.  Then use REPLACE to put one `.` in the 5th position.  Then use MROUND to round:

```
=MROUND(REPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""),5,0,"."),0.25)
```

[image]

If `.` is not your decimal separator then use this:

```
=REPLACE(MROUND(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1;".";"");6);25);5;0;".")
```

Comment: Unfortunately this formula doesn't work. I get a "You've entered too few arguments for this funtion" alert

Comment: on which part?  As you can see it works for me.  did you translate the formula?

Comment: How do I see in which part? After the alert appears the "." after the 5,0 is highlighted. I didn't translate it, except that I changed the comma for a semicolon. I'm on mac

Comment: If you are using `;` for the delimiter are your decimal separator `,` or `.`?

Comment: And does your output a string with the `.` or did you translate that also and want the `,`?

Comment: Also can you show me the actual formula you used, how you changed it?

Comment: =MROUND(REPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(I3;".";"");5,0;".");0.25)

Comment: you forgot the `,` between the `5` and the `0`.  that should also be a `;`  But this will not work because it relies on `.` being your decimal separator.

Comment: @MarkT see edit for one that should work with none `.` as a decimal separator.